# MongoDB find where user has both

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I don't really know how to phrase the subject of this question. Here's what I'm trying to do.

I have documents that look like this:

User 1 has one doc:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c8362762ee0d534e38fa7b1"),
"Reason" : "Reason 1",
"PUID" : "PUID11111",
"Activity" : "login",
}
```

User 1 has another doc:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c8362762ee0d534e38fa7c4"),
"Reason" : "Reason 2",
"PUID" : "PUID11111",
"Activity" : "login",
}
```

The `PUID` is the user identifier and the `Reason` can be multiple known values.

The search query I'm trying to build is --> I'm looking for all the `PUID`'s that have both `Reason` element `"Reason 1"` and `"Reason 2"`. If the PUID only has Reason element `"Reason 1"` or only `"Reason 2"` then this does not match. I'm trying to find users with both Reasons.

Any help would be appreciated. I've tried $where and distinct lookups but nothing seems to give me the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem. The idea is to use aggregation pipeline (sorry for tabs):

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
  $group: {
    _id: "$PUID",
    reasons: {
      $addToSet: "$Reason"
    }
  }
},
{
  $match: {
    reasons: {
      $all: ["Reason1", "Reason2"]
    }
  }
}])
```

At the group stage we group documents by PUID field and create a set of reasons (to avoid duplicates). At the match stage we just filter documents, which contain both reasons simultaneously.

**Edit**: switched to $all instead of $in, thanks JohnnyHK